How to prove that F∧φ is unsatisifiable doesn't mean F is unsatisfiable
The statement can be proven by contradiction. For instance, we can directly set $\phi$ as a contradictory formula and $F$ as a tautology. However, if we want to argue this point positively, how should we proceed?
Here are my thoughts：
Since $F \land \phi$ is unsatisfiable, it means that for any assignment $v$, we have $v(F \land \phi) = \text{False}$.
$\forall v, v(F \land \phi) = \text{False} \iff \forall v (v(F) = \text{False} \lor v(\phi) = \text{False})$
Since there is a disjunction symbol between them, this seems to indicate that $F$ is not necessarily unsatisfiable.However, I'm not sure if it is sufficient to prove that $F$ is unsatisfiable or if my reasoning is simply incorrect.

Let $F = { p }$ and $\varphi = \lnot p$.
